# Can you perform Magento UI_Component Validation with value from store config?

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, system.xml

Is it possible to get the minimum text length value from store config system.xml?

```
<field name="mytext" sortOrder="20" formElement="input">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">customer</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <label translate="true">MyText</label>
        <dataType>text</dataType>
        <dataScope>mytext</dataScope>
        <validation>
            <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
            <rule name="min_text_length" xsi:type="number">_____value from store config_____</rule>
        </validation>
    </settings>
</field>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<field id="show_items" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                <label>Default Items to Display</label>
                <validate>validate-number validate-digits validate-greater-than-zero no-whitespace validate-length maximum-length-3</validate>
                <comment>Maximum 999</comment>
            </field>
```

this is how you can validate your field in system.xml
for more validations you may refer to this link [Validation in Configuration](https://webkul.com/blog/validation-system-configuration-magento2/)

Comment: Sorry, that is not what I was asking. 
Can you use field from system.xml config for validation in customer_form.xml ui-component?